# Chaining two nullable Optional in one pipeline

Tags: java-8, option-type, flatmap

I have 2 Entity `EntityOne` and `EntityTwo` mapped to 2 tables in DB.
All columns in `EntityTwo` are present in `EntityOne` too, as `EntityTwo` is the read table for one sub-system.

Now, below is some code to explain a scenario,
I'm using spring data repo and java Optional, with java-8

```
    void doMagic(EntityOne entitytOne){   
        //Only if EntityOne present in Database, go delete entity Two.  
        repoOne
             .findById(entitytOne.getPrimaryKey()); //returns Optional<EntityOne>
             .ifPresent(this::deleteAssociatedEntityTwo);
    }

    void deleteAssociatedEntityTwo(EntityOne entityOne){
         // Only If able to find an EntityTwo associated with EntityOne in Database, then delete it
          fetchEntityTwo(entityOne) //returns Optional<EntityTwo>
                    .ifPresent(repoTwo::delete);
    }
```

Absent `EntityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey` is a method in `EntityOne` class which create a new EntityTwoPrimaryKey object and populate all values.

```
     private Optional<EntityTwo> fetchEntityTwo(EntityOne entityOne) {
        // Only if passed entityOne is not null, query the Db and return Optional<EntityTwo>
        return Optional
                .ofNullable(entityOne)
                .map(EntityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey)
                .map(repoTwo::findById) //returns Optional<EntityTwo>
                .orElse(Optional.empty());

    }
```

Now if you see in all above 3 methods have are optional checks to make sure action happen only if we have all data.
I want to write this all code in one optional pipeline.

If I write like below, There are no compilation errors. But what will happen when `repoOne.findById` cant find any data in database ?
I'm only checking `ifPresent()` after  `repoTwo::findById`

```
     repoOne.findById(entityOne.getEntityOnePrimaryKey())
            .map(entityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey) 
            .flatMap(repoTwo::findById) //returns Optional<EntityTwo>
            .ifPresent(repoTwo::delete);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's verify first if the resulting chain is correct, The first step would be breaking the methods into a single chain of `Optional` method calls.

```
void doMagic(EntityOne entityOne) {
    repoOne.findById(entityOne.getPrimaryKey())
           .ifPresent(eOne -> Optional
               .ofNullable(eOne)
               .map(entityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey)
               .flatMap(repoTwo::findById)
               .ifPresent(repoTwo::delete));
}
```

Now we can fold `entity -> Optional.ofNullable(entity)` with folded `ifPresent` into a flattened structure:

```
void doMagic(EntityOne entityOne) {
    repoOne.findById(entityOne.getPrimaryKey())
           .map(entityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey)
           .flatMap(repoTwo::findById)
           .ifPresent(repoTwo::delete);
}
```

So far so good, however, there is one more thing. But there is a dangerous thing, notice this line:

```
.map(entityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey)
```

What's wrong? This method reference doesn't call the `createEntityTwoPrimaryKey` method of the instance captured by the lambda expression but the one passed to the method itself! It'd be equivalent to:

```
.map(e -> entityOne.createEntityTwoPrimaryKey(e))
```

Which is **not** correct as is error-prone to NPE because `entityOne` can be `null`. You want to use:

```
// both are equivalent
.map(e -> e.createEntityTwoPrimaryKey(e))
.map(EntityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey)
```

So the final chain would look like:

```
void doMagic(EntityOne entityOne) {
    repoOne.findById(entityOne.getPrimaryKey())
           .map(EntityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey)
           .flatMap(repoTwo::findById)
           .ifPresent(repoTwo::delete);
}
```

Now the transformation is really correct, so let's go back to the question:

> If I write like below, There are no compilation errors. But what will happen when `repoOne.findById` can't find any data in the database? I'm only checking `ifPresent()` after `repoTwo::findById`.

Consider the following scenarios:

- `repoOne.findById` returns `Optional.empty()` - No subsequent `map` and `flatMap` are called, hence nothing is created. Also no `ifPresent` is called, hence nothing is deleted.
- `repoOne.findById` returns a non-empty `Optional` but `map` does - Again, everything from `flatMap` to the end is not called, hence nothing is created or deleted.
- Everything proceeding `flatMap` returns a non-empty `Optional`, but `flatMap` does - Here the things start to be interesting because `createEntityTwoPrimaryKey` is whatever it does, but the removal in `ifPresent` is not. However, I assume if something is created it would be also most likely be found, so this scenario is really an edge case.
- The final result depends on the `delete` method call, however, it is of the `void` return type. As long as no `RuntimeException` is thrown, it is safe.

Summary, I find the `Optional` chain safe. You might want to annotate the method with `@Transactional` to rollback on possible `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Hi Regarding the `ifPresent(entityTwo::delete)` that was a typo. I corrected to `ifPresent(repoTwo::delete)`, However your other assumption is wrong, the code I gave it right...`createEntityTwoPrimaryKey` is in 'EntityOne`.   if you look at the comment about this method it explains.. what it does

Comment: Is the `createEntityTwoPrimaryKey` method `static`?

Comment: Oh, I updated, the case to `entityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey` from `EntityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey`  for clarity.. ...so now its not static but coming from the state of entityOne.......but how does this affect the problem  about Optional pipeline I was asking about  ?

Comment: Your answer look exactly same as what I mentioned in my question..  If you read the last line in my question that is the main question .

Comment: One clarification on your assumption, although I did mentione it in question.... `entityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey`  creates new java Object and populating the value....It is NOT CREATING any entity in DB... Only code which can return `empty` is `repoOne.findById` or `repoTwoFindbyId`... either one or both...... Little background why all this...... I'm trying to create a robust sync job which periodically run and update a domain repo in correct state by collecting data from many different backend services. I'm also NOT generating any primaryKey.. using primaryKey values from backend system

Comment: There is a huge difference between `entityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey` and `EntityOne::createEntityTwoPrimaryKey`. Please, next time post exactly the same code. It's very hard to amend my answer with each your change...